# If we assume that their is a prime between n and 2n...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If we assume that their is a prime between 'n' and '2n' then, how to prove that any integer greater than 1 can be written as sum of two primes?(In this we treat 1 as a prime)

Comment: This is false. The first assumption is always true, because of Bertrand's postulate. The second claim, however is not true in general.

Answer (score 4):

It is simply not true that any integer can be written as the sum of two primes. $11$ is the smallest counterexample.

That every even integer (greater that $2$) can be written as the sum of two primes is known as Goldbach's conjecture, and is still not proven.